# Warranty Question

Tags: warranty

If I brought in an Apple product under warranty, and they determined that a part of it was broken, but I didn't bring it in until after the warranty expired, will they still replace the part for free?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the answer would be no.

However, you can usually get further by calling apple's 800#, whining and complaining like a sorority girl, and begging your heart out.

It works.

Anything you have which MIGHT be useful as manipulation may help you as well.. your mom died the last week of warranty, your cat got eaten by a snake, etc....

I know it sounds trite, but IF it's something that apple has a general "REA" covering (essentially an extended warranty, due to their knowledge of issues), there is a lot more leeway...